# Is 55 minutes layover in Dusseldorf possible?

Tags: layovers, short-connections, dus

I'm planning to travel from Tokyo to Hamburg, my ticket is like below:

Tokyo Narita > Dusseldorf (ANA)

55 minutes layover

Dusseldorf > Hamburg (Eurowing)

Since I have never been at Dusseldorf Airport before, I want to ask if that 55 minutes layover is enough?

Apparently, I have to get out the plane at International terminal, go through customs (I have a long term, multiple entries Schengen VISA) and navigate to Domestic terminal.

Thank you all.

Comment: Single ticket or two different tickets? Checked bags or carry-on only ?

Comment: @Hilmar single ticket issued by ANA. I have checked bags.

Comment: Should be fine then. Even if you miss it, they just going to put you on the next flight. Since Eurowings is part of Lufthansa group, you probably would have access to LH flights as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Dusseldorf Airport is not a very big airport. 55 minutes are well doable and the major obstacle will be the length of the non-EU passport check/immigration queue. 
But I would personally not worry about it as most passengers from Japan should have an easy case, which makes the queues move quickly. You will not share the queue with EU citizens, as they have automated passport gates available for them.

There is no separate international terminal. Most likely, you will have to walk from the B gates to the A gates, which takes ~5-10 minutes.

You will not pass through customs with your checked luggage but head straight to your next gate after your passport check. Your luggage will be sent straight to the flight to Hamburg and you pass through customs there.

Answer (score 3):

I'm posting an answer since I don't have enough reputation to comment `DCTLib`'s answer. His luggage won't be sent straight to the flight to Hamburg. If I'm not mistaken, he is taking Eurowings from Dusseldorf to Hamburg, which means that this flight is independent of the flight from Tokyo to Dusseldorf since low-cost carriers mostly don't offer transfers. He is entering the EU/Schengen and passing customs in Dusseldorf

Comment: The OP wrote that both flights are on the same ticket. A 55 minutes connection would also be too short to collect the bag and check it in again. Note that Eurowings flights *can* be part of a traditional ticket. For instance, if you book on Lufthansa's website, you can frequently get them as part of a journey with traditional carriers.